# What happened to constructor argument injection when getting instances of objects in StructureMap's ObjectFactory?

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

Trying to upgrade/convert to StructureMap 3.0 from 2.6

I have code that manually set constructor arguments via the `With` method off of the ObjectFactory

```
ObjectFactory.With(ctorArgument).GetInstance<ClassThatHasACtorArgument>();
```

What is the StructureMap 3.0 equivalent now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh... it was moved into the global container...

```
ObjectFactory.Container.With(ctorArgument).GetInstance<ClassThatHasACtorArgument>();
```